# Importing nested COM references

Tags: c#, visual-studio, com, vb6

In Visual Studio 2015 if I create a "class library" C# project and then add a reference to a custom COM DLL (created using VB6), *VS will then also automatically add all (?) the COM references that the VB6 DLL depends on*.

**How does it do this?** How can it statically figure out what those references are?

Note -- Our VB6 DLL uses "early binding", but even still there is no equivalent of an imports table for COM items like you would see in a traditional "C" style DLL.

Answer (score 6):

You are actually adding a reference to a *type library*.  It is embedded inside the DLL as a resource.  You can see it when you use File > Open > File, select the DLL, open the TYPELIB node.  It plays the exact same role as metadata in a .NET assembly, listing the type definitions of the exposed interfaces and classes.  It has a binary format, you can decompile it with the OleView.exe utility.

And has dependency info as well, the registry helps to find such dependent type libraries (HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Classes\Typelib key).  Roughly the same role that the GAC plays in .NET.  COM just isn't as different from .NET as everybody assumes :)   The first version of the CLR was created by the COM+ group at Microsoft.  Eliminating the registration and DLL Hell problems associated with COM were on the top of the todo list.

Type libraries are not exactly legacy, they still play a pivotal role in the brand-new WinRT (aka UWP, aka Modern UI).  Which is COM-based at its core, very well hidden.  But the olden format was retired because of limitations, replaced by the .winmd format.  Which is exactly the same as the .NET metadata format.  Any .NET decompiler can show their content.

Comment: *And has dependency info as well, the registry helps to find such dependent type libraries (HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Classes\Typelib key)* – Where, exactly, is this dependency info?

Comment: In the type library.  Use Oleview.exe to see it, importlib() statements.

Comment: Hm, it seems TLB indeed references imported libraries.  However, tlbimp.exe & co. seem to only traverse the data available from `ITypeLib`, which in turn returns `ITypeInfo` for interfaces, structs, etc. that contain further `ITypeInfo`s (e.g. inheritance, method arguments, method return type or field type) that may be contained in other type libraries, essentially through `ITypeInfo::GetContainingTypeLib`.

Comment: The latest source code of OleView.exe that I have says in tlbodl.cpp: *There most likely were "importlib()" statements in in the source.  While it appears possible to be able to identify them, it is non-trivial and is currently not supported.* Also: *TODO:  Grovel through all typeinfos for any referenced types that are defined in imported libs*  I gather that OleView currently takes the then-not-yet-done approach.

Comment: Ok, I've seen a few type libraries with OleView, and the `importlib` statements it generates reflect current registered type libraries, although the LIBID seems to come internally from the type library without searching in the registry in HKCR\Interface.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that Visual Studio type library importer chases type library dependencies is to gather type information to map to .NET.

A type library doesn't have direct dependency information.  So this is a very good question: how to track type library dependencies?

The only *feasible* way to detect type library dependencies is by referring to a type which states the declaring type library.

For instance, if your type library references `IXMLDOMDocument` in a method's signature, it'll be recorded in a type info record.

You can crawl a type library, by loading one, getting a `ITypeLib` from it and enumerating `ITypeInfo`s recursively.

You'll eventually see this record.  Then, you can get the type's containing type library ID through `ITypeInfo::GetContainingTypeLib`.  If it refers to another type library, you found a dependency.

A crawler may track dependencies all the way until it has no more type libraries to load.

You don't have to crawl every type of every type library to find the strictly necessary set of types, but the job of the type library importer is to mirror type library information to .NET type info and metadata assemblies, so it imports type libraries in full.  It's easier to implement, to explain/understand what it's doing and the output is reusable outside the context of the root type library.

If you didn't use early binding, your type library would instead mention `IDispatch`, `IUnknown` and/or `VARIANT`, which would make it impossible to detect any dependency.

You may use registration-free COM in isolated applications to have the dependencies sorted out, but it still doesn't have to be a proper dependency tree, e.g. you may state all dependencies in one manifest.

And remember that type library != DLL.  A type library may be embedded as a resource in a DLL or in its own TLB file.

So, this whole talk is about **type** dependencies, not **class/component** or other runtime dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is actually statically analyzing all the dependencies.

I think it is just adding the COM references which are part of the public API of the DLL. These would be plainly visible in the typelib which is part of the DLL, as far as I understand it.

Probably other dependencies which are used internally but not in the public interface are neglected.